# Generate all points on the perimeter of a diamond

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, coordinates

Given a series of diamonds like this:

[image]

How does one generate a list of the black squares for each diamond? Assume the red square is at {0, 0} and the coordinates of the black squares are given relative to that. Examples for the given diamonds:

```
0 = {0, 0}
1 = {-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}
2 = {-2, 0}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {0, -2}, {0, 2}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}
3 = {-3, 0}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {0, -3}, {0, 3}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}
```

Observations (given n is the distance from origin to corner):

- The sum of each coordinate pair is always n or -n.
- With the exception of 0, the size of the list is always 4n.
- |x| + |y| = n is the Cartesian equation of the diamond.

With the lattermost observation I discovered the following solution in C. But it's in O(n^2) time with a comparison and two calls to abs(). Is there not a faster solution suitable for much larger diamonds?

```
void diamond_points(int n) {
    for (int x = -n; x <= n; ++x) {
        for (int y = -n; y <= n; ++y) {
            if (abs(x) + abs(y) == n) {
                printf("{%d, %d}, ", x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, with O(N)

```
for(int x = -n; x <= n; x++) {
    int y = n - abs(x);
    printf("{%d, %d}, ", x, y);
    if(y > 0) {
        printf("{%d, %d}, ", x, -y);
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of a micro-optimization, but I think you could remove the if-statement if you brought the y==0 case outside the loop: https://pastebin.com/raw/mC51ZmYT

Comment: Well, if you value every millisecond, then you should try to get rid of all possible `if`s :) @DragonDePlatino